# Fast way to split string and convert to long format in data.table

Tags: r, substring, data.table, data-manipulation

I do the following

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)        
dt <- data.table(string_column = paste(sample(c(letters, " "), 500000, replace = TRUE)
                                     , sample(c(letters, " "), 500000, replace = TRUE)
                                     , sample(1:500000)
                                 , sep = " "), key = "string_column") 

split_res <- dt[, list(name = unlist(str_split(string_column, '\\s+'))), by = string_column]
```

For real data, it takes approx. 1 hour to process `dt` (10M rows) and create `split_res` (18M rows)
Out of curiosity - is there way to speed up process? Maybe `unlist + str_split` is not the right way of doing this?

Comment: Please post minimum sample data

Comment: You have duplicated values in your present "string_column" variable. Should this be the case?

Comment: no, sorry, needed unique rows (got rid of replace = TRUE )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll get a big speedup if you just ditch using `str_split()` from "stringr" and just use `strsplit()`.

```
fun1 <- function() dt[, list(name = unlist(str_split(string_column, '\\s+'))), by = string_column]
fun2 <- function() dt[, list(name = unlist(strsplit(string_column, '\\s+'))), by = string_column]

system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  172.41    0.05  172.82 

system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   11.22    0.01   11.23
```

Whether this will make your processing time down from one hour to 4 minutes or not, I'm not sure. But at least you won't have to remember to put in those pesky underscores in your function names :-)

---

If you can split on a fixed search pattern, you can use the `fixed = TRUE` argument, which will give you another substantial speed boost.

---

Another thing to consider is to do the process manually:

```
x <- strsplit(dt$string_column, "\\s+")
DT <- dt[rep(sequence(nrow(dt)), vapply(x, length, 1L))]
DT[, name := unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)]
DT
```

With your sample data:

```
fun4 <- function() {
  x <- strsplit(dt$string_column, "\\s+")
  DT <- dt[rep(sequence(nrow(dt)), vapply(x, length, 1L))]
  DT[, name := unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)]
  DT
}
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.79    0.01    1.82
```

However, the answer is not the same as what I get with `fun2()`, but that's because you have duplicated values in "string_column". If you add an "id" column and do the same, you will get the same results.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I have tenfold speed up - was -  3660s, now - 370s